# Google Maps JavaScript API in a Flex app using ColdFusion CFC & SQL Server to get addresses

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, google-maps, coldfusion, cfc

Still pretty new to Flex. I'm trying to incorporate the Google Maps JavaScript API into my Flex application while pulling the marker data from a database via ColdFusion.

The application is supposed to pull all the students who attend a particular school and then display the students via markers on the map. It's also supposed to display the school, but I haven't gotten to that yet.

I have most of it written but I'm stuck on what may end up being a simple part. I have the map created, and I have the CFC pulling the coordinate data but then I get errors when I try to return the data back to the action script page.

I'm getting "The value returned from the getGeoInfo function is not of type Query." I realize that maybe I'm using the wrong `returntype`, but I'm not sure what else to use.

Here is an example of what the CFC is returning.

```
28.5980179,-81.3651601;28.5383355,-81.3792365
```

Here are my actionscript functions for getting the geographical locations:

```
/** getGeoInfo
* get the Geographical Data
*
* @param void
* @return void
*/

private function getGeoInfo():void
{
    try
    { 
        var myArgs:Object = new Object;
        /* myArgs.column_list = "GeoCode, Student_Address, Student_Name_First, Student_Name_Last"; */
        remotingDelegate.callCFC("getGeoInfo", myArgs);
    }

    catch (error:Error)
    {
        FlexException.errorHandler(error, "StudentPopMapModuleCode:getGeoInfo");
    }
}


/**
* getGeoInfo_Handler
* The handler of the remoting call    
* @param Object results The results of the remoting call
* @return void
*/

public function getGeoInfo_Handler(results:ArrayCollection):void
{
    try
    { 
        geoInfoAC = results;
    }

    catch (error:Error)
    {
    FlexException.errorHandler(error, "StudentPopMapModuleCode:getGeoInfo_Handler");
    }
}
```

and here is the code on the mxml page to receive the coordinates:

```
public function onMapReady(event:MapEvent):void {
    map.setCenter(new LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419), 13, MapType.NORMAL_MAP_TYPE);
    for each (var o:Object in geoInfoAC){
        var md:MarkerData = o["markerData"] as MarkerData;
        var latlng:LatLng = new LatLng(md.lat,md.lng);
        var marker:Marker= new Marker(latlng);
        addMarker(md,marker); 
    }
}

public function addMarker(markerData:MarkerData, marker:Marker):void{
    var o:Object = {markerData:markerData,marker:marker};
    marker.addEventListener(MapMouseEvent.CLICK,markerClicked);
    marker.addEventListener(InfoWindowClosedEvent.NAME,closed);
    markerData.marker = marker;
    map.addOverlay(marker);
    dataProvider.addItem(o); 
    dataProvider.refresh(); 
}

public function closed(event:InfoWindowClosedEvent):void{
    var marker:Marker = event.marker;
    var latLng:LatLng = marker.getLatLng();
    var markerData:MarkerData = new MarkerData(latLng.lat(),latLng.lng()/* ,event.inputName */);
    var o:Object = MapUtils.getMarkerDataByLatAndLng(latLng.lat(),latLng.lng(),dataProvider);
    if (o == null){
        addMarker(markerData,marker);
    }else{
        o["markerData"] = markerData;
    dataProvider.refresh();
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I might have missed something, but getGeoInfo isn't returning anything

Comment: getGeoInfo is remote calling getGeoInfo.cfc  and that is returning a var called getInfo with a returntype of Query & a value of 28.5980179,-81.3651601;28.5383355,-81.3792365.

Unfortunately, my procedure needs an ArrayCollection and it can't convert 28.5980179,-81.3651601;28.5383355,-81.3792365 to AC but I'm not sure what returntype to use and how to update the handler accordingly.

Comment: I changed the returntype to String and the function handler is now:

 public function getGeoInfo_Handler(results:String):void

That seems to have fixed the error, but I'm not sure why the function on the mxml page isn't picking up getInfoAC.

Comment: So despite changing it to string, the function needs the values as Number in order to convert them to coordinates for longitude and latitude. 

I'm not sure how/where to make this change.  Also, should I change them before entering them into the array? After?

Comment: Turns out that because it was being treated as a string, I needed to split the array by each coordinate. I used the following and it worked. 

public function onMapReady(event:MapEvent):void {
    map.setCenter(new LatLng(28.5383355,-81.3792365), 11, MapType.NORMAL_MAP_TYPE);            
    
    for each (var o:Object in geoInfoAC){
     var latlngArray:Array = o.split(",");     
     var md:MarkerData = new MarkerData(latlngArray[0],latlngArray[1]);
     var latlng:LatLng = new LatLng(md.lat,md.lng);
     var marker:Marker= new Marker(latlng);
     addMarker(md,marker);

Comment: Whoops, forgot to mention that the handler had to be updated as well:

 public function getGeoInfo_Handler(results:String):void
 {
  try
  {   
   geoInfoAC = new ArrayCollection(results.split(";"));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that because it was being treated as a string, I needed to split the array by each coordinate. I used the following and it worked.

The handler was updated to:

```
public function getGeoInfo_Handler(results:String):void { 
try { geoInfoAC = new ArrayCollection(results.split(";"));
```

Then on the actual mxml page I used:

```
public function onMapReady(event:MapEvent):void { 
map.setCenter(new LatLng(28.5383355,-81.3792365), 11, MapType.NORMAL_MAP_TYPE); 
for each (var o:Object in geoInfoAC){
var latlngArray:Array = o.split(","); 
var md:MarkerData = new MarkerData(latlngArray[0],latlngArray[1]); 
var latlng:LatLng = new LatLng(md.lat,md.lng); 
var marker:Marker= new Marker(latlng); addMarker(md,marker);
```

Hope this helps someone.